# How can I set scheduledtask without prompting for a password

Tags: c++, mfc, scheduled-tasks, shellexecute, windows-task-scheduler

I have an application which needs to set a scheduled tasks in Windows.
For this I have used the ShellExecute function to call the schtasks.exe

I have used the following code :

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("schtasks.exe"), _T("/create /TN SampleSchedule /TR calc.exe /SC DAILY /ST 12:15:00 /SD 09/04/2012"),_T(""),0);
```

but it has not created the scheduled task.

But when I changed the last parameter of ShellExecute function (display command prompt) to 1

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("schtasks.exe"), _T("/create /TN SampleSchedule /TR calc.exe /SC DAILY /ST 12:15:00 /SD 09/04/2012"),_T(""),1);
```

a command prompt displayed and it asked for the password of the current logged in user.

The /RU SYSTEM is working, but I would like to run as the current logged in user itself without asking for the password....

Is it possible? If yes, what should I do for that?

Comment: have you got any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Use  ITaskScheduler COM interface instead.

Examples of using it  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446856%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13089/Harnessing-the-task-scheduler)